# How can I print Views Exposed Filter widgets individually using views-exposed-form--mypage.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, views

I have five exposed filter widgets that appear on this page.  I would like to group three of them together and add a title above that group of three so that my layout goes from:

*views default*

- A
- B
- C
- D
- E

*what I want*

- A
- TITLE

  - B
  - C
  - D
- E

Since this customization is specific to one page, I added a `views-exposed-form--mypage.tpl.php` in my theme's template folder.

The code looks like this:

```
<div class="views-exposed-widgets clearfix">
    <?php foreach ($widgets as $id => $widget): ?>
      <div id="<?php print $widget->id; ?>-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-<?php print $id; ?>">
        <?php if (!empty($widget->label)): ?>
          <label for="<?php print $widget->id; ?>">
            <?php print $widget->label; ?>
          </label>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (!empty($widget->operator)): ?>
          <div class="views-operator">
            <?php print $widget->operator; ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="views-widget">
          <?php print $widget->widget; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php if (!empty($sort_by)): ?>
      <div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-sort-by">
        <?php print $sort_by; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-sort-order">
        <?php print $sort_order; ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Instead of the foreach loop, how can I print the individual widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="views-exposed-widgets clearfix">
    <?php foreach ($widgets as $id => $widget): 
       if ($id == 'SOMETHING_ID_THATIDENTIFY_B') {
         print '<div id="BCD">'.t('TITLE');
       }
       else if ($id == 'SOMETHING_ID_THATIDENTIFY_E') {
         print '</div>'; //Closing #BCD
       }
    ?>

      <div id="<?php print $widget->id; ?>-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-<?php print $id; ?>">
        <?php if (!empty($widget->label)): ?>
          <label for="<?php print $widget->id; ?>">
            <?php print $widget->label; ?>
          </label>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (!empty($widget->operator)): ?>
          <div class="views-operator">
            <?php print $widget->operator; ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="views-widget">
          <?php print $widget->widget; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php if (!empty($sort_by)): ?>
      <div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-sort-by">
        <?php print $sort_by; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-sort-order">
        <?php print $sort_order; ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!  `$id` should be `$widget->id`, but otherwise it works!